# how to remove style makeStyle?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've been working on React App and i have a problem with empty space padding i can't find it

I tried to use inspect to find it

[image]

the style in inspect is

[image]

and my style is

```
* {

}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

my code is

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div>
       
        </div>
)}
export default App
```

please can anyone help my with this?

Comment: You have defined something related to this in your `material component`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CSS snippet:

```
* { border: 1px solid black; }
```

Every element should now get a border. Beware, this means everything. Hopefuly it'll help you figure out that white space in your app!

Include that CSS snippet before your CSS files so that it can be overwritten - or after, to force it onto every element.